# Module load/unload commands in Linux scripts

Tags: linux, module, load, environment-modules

I often have a need to create Linux scripts which contain `module load` and `module unload` commands.  Is there a way to test if a module is already loaded before executing a `module unload` command?

The reason why I need to do this is that if I have a `module unload` command and the module in question is not already loaded, then it will result in error messages.  I would like to avoid these error messages by testing for the module being already loaded, and unloading it only if this is the case.

Comment: According to your comment you don't seem to mean Linux kernel modules but a less commonly used software, I guess this: http://modules.sourceforge.net/, https://www.mpcdf.mpg.de/services/computing/software/modules Please [edit] your question and add this information. Please show the exact commands you would use manually and the output of `module list`.

Comment: The load and unload commands are 'module load <modulename>' and 'module unload <modulename>

Comment: Here is the output of the module list command:  Currently Loaded Modulefiles:
   1) unix/1.0/b                   6) questa/10.2c/a
   2) ede/1.0/b                    7) slickedit/2015/a
   3) lsf/8.0/a                    8) synplifypro/j2014.09sp1/a
   4) adobereader/9.4-1/a          9) ise-ds/14.7/a
   5) git/2.19.1/a

Comment: could you precise the version of module you use (type `module -V`) ? `module` command does not shoot and error when a not loaded module is unloaded

Answer (score 1):

[Recent versions of the `module` command (4+)](https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/stable/MIGRATING.html) have a new sub-command called `is-loaded` which returns true or false whether a given module is loaded or not.

So to conditionally unload a module from a shell session, you could type:

```
module is-loaded $MODULENAME && module unload $MODULENAME
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the kind of solution I was looking for.  Unfortunately, the version I have doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the question is not related  to Linux modules but to this software: https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/stable/module.html

The `grep` pattern assumes that the module name is the first word of the `module list` output. This will be fixed when the missing information is added to the question.

```
# example for unloading
MODULENAME=foobar
module list | grep -qw "^$MODULENAME" && module unload "$MODULENAME"
```

```
# example for loading
MODULENAME=foobar
module list | grep -qw "^$MODULENAME" || module load "$MODULENAME"
```

Comment: Actually, "module list" will display a list of the modules that are loaded.  What I really am looking for is something like the following:if [     ]; then
   module unload $MODULENAME
fi

Answer (score 0):

OK I think the [answer of Bodo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56633334/4062818) is close but this is tricky because at least my module command prints to the error output but I think OK solution for loading modules would be:

```
function LoadModule()
{
    if module list 2>&1| grep -qw $1; then
        echo "Module $1 already loaded."
    else
        echo "Loading module $1."
        module load $1
    fi
}

function UnloadModule()
{
    if module list 2>&1| grep -qw $1; then
        echo "Unloading module $1."
        module unload $1
    else
        echo "Module $1 is not loaded."
    fi
}
```